# Udp client on java android

Tags: android, sockets, udp, client, send

so this simple app always throws exception and return "error"

main
package com.asd;
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

import android.view.*;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.*;

public class Test extends Activity {

```
public EditText et1;
@Override``
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              try{
               DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();       
               InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.3"); 
                     byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];    
                     et1.setText(et1.getText().toString()+"sending");  
                    String sentence = et1.getText().toString();   
                    sendData = sentence.getBytes(); 


                 DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 5014);

                      clientSocket.send(sendPacket); 
                      et1.setText(et1.getText().toString()+"sent"); 
                 clientSocket.close();}
              catch (Exception e) {et1.setText(et1.getText().toString()+"error"); }
           }
         };
         but1.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return true;

}
```

}